# Using a default value for a function parameter which depends of other parameter

Tags: raku

I'd like to create an script which takes an input file and optionally an output file. When you don't pass an output file, the script uses the same filename as the input but with the extension changed. I don't know how to write a default parameter which changes the extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

unit sub MAIN(
  Str $input where *.IO.f, #= input file
  Str $output = $input.IO.extension("txt"), #= output file
  Bool :$copy, #= copy file
  Bool :$move, #= move file
);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work:

```
No such method 'IO' for invocant of type 'VMNull'
  in block <unit> at ./copy.raku line 5
```

How can I do something like that?

Comment: This looks very much like a bug.

Comment: Yes, looks very much like some weird codegenning / binding / dispatch bug.  It looks though that removing the `#=` strings has a beneficial effect.

Comment: Thanks!. I deleted the comment as workaround.

Comment: [Issue filed](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5100).

Answer (score 5):

error message is less than awesome but program not working is expected because you have in the signature

```raku
Str $output = $input.IO.extension("txt")
```

but the right hand side returns an `IO::Path` object with that extension but `$output` is typed to be a String. That is an error:

```raku
>>> my Str $s := "file.csv".IO.extension("txt")
Type check failed in binding; expected Str but got IO::Path (IO::Path.new("file.t...)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

```raku
>>> sub fun(Str $inp, Str $out = $inp.IO.extension("txt")) { }
&fun

>>> fun "file.csv"
Type check failed in binding to parameter '$out'; expected Str but got IO::Path (IO::Path.new("file.t...)
  in sub fun at <unknown file> line 1
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Sometimes compiler detects incompatible default values:

```raku
>>> sub yes(Str $s = 3) { }
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Default value '3' will never bind to a parameter of type Str
------> sub yes(Str $s = 3⏏) { }
    expecting any of:
        constraint
```

but what you have is far from a literal, so runtime detection.

To fix it, you can either

- change to `Str() $output = $inp.IO.extension("txt")` where `Str()` means "accept Any object and then cast it to Str". So `$output` will end up being a string like `"file.txt"` available in MAIN.

  - similar alternative: `Str $output = $inp.IO.extension("txt").Str` but it's repetitive in `Str`.
- change to `IO::Path() $output = $inp.IO.extension("txt")`. Similarly, this casts to whatever recieved to an `IO::Path` object, so, e.g., you'll have `"file.txt".IO` available in `$output`. If you do this, you might want to do the same for `$input` as well for consistency. Since `IO::Path` objects are idempotent to `.IO` (in `eqv` sense), no other part of the code needs changing.

Comment: If you have arrived here having searched for `invocant of type 'VMNull'` or similar please see [the extraordinarily weird bug that led to that error message in this case](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5100).